# Prevent jQuery execution inside of VueJS generated code

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working to replace jQuery with VueJS but my old jQuery code is still executing on VueJS generated code.

There is a way to prevent jQuery code to be executed on VueJS code ?

I can't simply disable jQuery on VueJS page because some part of page still need jQuery.

I think I should check a HTML has `data-v-xxxxx` attribute and then prevent jQuery execution on it.

I don't find a way to prevent jQuery execution on some tags.

Is this doable or I need to find another way ?

Comment: What do you mean? jQuery doesn't execute itself unless you select an element or enable a plugin that does stuff on your page.

Comment: Yes I know but I have some global code who modify states or content of some tags. I'm trying to find a global solution instead adding a condition on each global code.

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing that. You can add a class to every root element you set for your vue instances works (the one you use with `el : '#element'`. A class like `vuejs` and in every global function, in your selector, add a `.not('.vuejs, .vuejs *')`

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your app it is very difficult to suggest a solution. Anyway
here is a take.

Suppose your old HTML/jQuery is structured this way:

```
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <header>
        <!-- Some complicated HTML for the header !-->
        </header>

        <!-- Rest of the app !-->
        <div class="someContainer"></div>

    </div>
```

Assuming you started to refactor the header as a vueJs component, you can try
isolating this from jQuery by using CSS selectors and event delegation.

CSS selector will allow you select elements only inside certain elements.

```
    // before
    const $root = $(".mainDiv");

    // after
    const $root = $(".someContainer");

    // select an element inside the new root
    $root.find("p")
    // catch all clicks inside this root.
    $root.on("click", e => {});
```

What you could do, although I won't recommend it is passing around a new version
off the jQuery object which already pre select the correct root.

For instance if your app has some `$("selector").click()` everywhere in your
app, you could then alias the global `$` to a new function:

```
    jQuery.noConflict(); // will restore the old $ global var
    const $root = jQuery(".someContainer");
    // very basic and incomplete proposal
    const $ = function (...args) {
        return $root.find.apply($root, args);
    };
    window.$ = $; // make it globally available.
```